# Replace NaN with values from other column based on certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set looks like the following with multi indices (No. and type) and want to replace NaN value in column l2 of type Node1 and Node2 with R1 value from l2 and replace NaN values of type Node3 and Node4 with l2 values of R2. 
How can I do this in pandas?

```
    name    l1          l2
No. type        
1   Node1   41.656123   NaN
    Node2   95.232711   NaN
    Node3   41.660935   NaN
    Node4   95.144500   NaN
    R1       NaN    0.000144
    R2       NaN    0.000154
2   Node1   41.656142   NaN
    Node2   95.232730   NaN
    Node3   41.660957   NaN
    Node4   95.144525   NaN
    R1       NaN    0.000200
    R2       NaN    0.000232
```

The expected outcome should look like:

```
    name    l1          l2
No. type        
1   Node1   41.656123   0.000144
    Node2   95.232711   0.000144
    Node3   41.660935   0.000154
    Node4   95.144500   0.000154
    R1       NaN    0.000144
    R2       NaN    0.000154
2   Node1   41.656142   0.000200
    Node2   95.232730   0.000200
    Node3   41.660957   0.000232
    Node4   95.144525   0.000232
    R1       NaN    0.000200
    R2       NaN    0.000232
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Comment: @Emma is this what you wanted? So that we help, let us know if you expected something else

Comment: Actually, I want the condition to be something like: if type is Node1 or Node2 then replace l2 of these nodes with l2 from R1, else if type is Node3 or Node4 then replace l2 with l2 from R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) dataframe with `type` that is eq to either `R1` or `R2` and [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the R1 and R2 with Node1 and Node 2 respectively

```
df1=df.query('type == ["R2", "R1"]').reset_index()f#filter Rs to be renamed as Nodes for purposes of joining down the line
df3=df.query('type == ["R2", "R1"]').reset_index()#.set_index('No.')# filter of Rs not to be renamed but to be reappended later
df1.replace(['R1','R2'], ['Node1','Node3'], inplace=True)
```

[Drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) `l2` beacuse you do not need it here, it has `NaNs` and reset index

```
df1.drop(columns=['l1'], inplace=True)
df1.set_index(['No.','type'], inplace=True)
df1
```

Extract dataframe with `type` that is not eq to either `R1` or `R2`

```
df2=df.query('type != ["R2", "R1"]').reset_index()#.set_index('No.')
```

Drop `l2` beacuse you do not need it here, it has `NaNs` and reset index

```
df2.drop(columns=['l2'], inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['No.','type'], inplace=True)
df2
```

[Merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two dataframes

```
df4=df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer').ffill()
```

Call back a fillter of the `Rs` and set index to conform to the `df4`

```
df3.set_index(['No.','type'], inplace=True)
df3
```

Append `df3` to `df4` and sort by index

```
final=df4.append(df3).sort_index()
final
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I want the output to look like:  name l1 l2
No. type  
1 Node1 41.656123 0.000144
 Node2 95.232711 0.000144
 Node3  41.660935 0.000154
 Node4 95.144500 0.000154
 R1 NaN 0.000144
 R2 NaN 0.000154
2 Node1 41.656142 0.000200
 Node2 95.232730 0.000200
 Node3  41.660957 0.000232
 Node4 95.144525 0.000232
 R1 NaN 0.000200
 R2 NaN 0.000232

Comment: I cant see clearky from the comnent because not formatted. Could you please edit question snd insert expected outcome so that we help?

Comment: I have edited the question by adding the expected outcome. thanks.

Comment: Try the edited version. The downside of not giving an expected outcome is insertions have to be made to amend the answer to your fit. That at times makes the code longer. Try in future to put the expected outcome beforehand. Let me know if happy else we assist more.

Comment: thanks, it worked, though I had to add df3.replace(['R1','R2'], ['Node2','Node4'], inplace=True) and modified accordingly.